# Angular 6 ngFor list does not update automatically after new insertion

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN app and I am having a problem with `*ngFor` list not updating after I create a new item.  I know the item has been created successfully as the list updates if I refresh manually, but it does not update automatically.

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { myThings } from '../things';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

export class AuthService {
constructor(private http:Http, private hTTp:HttpClient) { }
getThings():Observable<myThings[]>{
  const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.append('Authorization', token);
  headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.hTTp.get<myThings[]>('http://localhost:3000/things/get', { headers: headers });
}
}
```

**things.ts**

```
export interface myThings {
    _id:String,
    user:String,
    name:String,
    devicetype:String,
    state: Boolean,
    analog:Number,
    timestamp:String
}
```

**things.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-things',
  templateUrl: './things.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./things.component.css']
})
export class ThingsComponent implements OnInit {
  things = [];
  noThings: Boolean;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private validateService:ValidateService, private http:Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getThings().subscribe(things => {
      if (things) {
        this.things = things;
        this.noThings = false;
      }
      else {
        this.noThings = true;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**things.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!noThings">
  <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createThing">Create thing</a>
  <ul *ngFor="let thing of things">
    <li>Thing: {{thing.name}} Type: {{thing.devicetype}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What is causing the list not to update once the data has been added successfully?

Please note that I have read all other related questions but could not resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you receive a new instance of the array in your subscription or is it the same with just a new entry added?

Comment: Did you verify in the network panel of the browser that the GET request was successful.

Comment: @Shivam, I believe that getThings will only fire once onInit.  If you want to update things[], you need to call it again, or push your thing to things (locally) once you've successfully created thing.

Comment: @Farasi78 Thanks! I created a function and called it in the onInit as well as every time I create, delete or update an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Farasi78 the getThings was called only once. So, I created a function handleThingList(), which is called at onInit as well as every time a new item is inserted in the list

handleThingList()

```
this.authService.getThings().subscribe(things => {
      if (things) {
        this.things = things;
        this.noThings = false;
      }
      else {
        this.noThings = true;
      }
    })
```

I don't know if this is the right approach. But it works!

Thank you all for your kind answers!

Comment: Hope this could work if the data is got and loaded from the api or db. Currently I am using localstorage and seems it does not load the current data. I eventually get the correct list after a refresh or if I move our and back in to the component.